# datepicker y formato

Tags: php, datepicker

estoy haciendo una web "simple" en teoria pero como no tengo tanta exp en programacion si me tomo mi tiempo para avanzar.

Hoy tengo este inconveniente, al momento de cargar una pestaña, en el formulario me sale un mensaje raro y creo que es por el tema de formatos de fecha, ese error desaparece hasta que haga clic en algun mes del calendario que se despliega y le presiono a mostrar.

El boton hace eso porque queria mostrar la fecha elegida, cada vez que elegia una fecha se quedaba en blanco, buscando por foros y la web encontre que añadiendo value al input me mostraba los datos.

Trate de separar los datos (mes-año) y luego agruparlos en otra variable pero no ayudo mucho tampoco
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el primero es un input que uso y pido que me muestre lo que guarda el datepicker y lo otro es como separe la data obtenida en 2 variables para poder hacer mis consultas mysql ya que solo usan meses y años.

```
<input type="text" class="hasdatepicker" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" value="<?php echo $_POST['datepicker'] ?>" />                    
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Mostrar">
<script>$(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
format: "yyyy-mm",
startView: "months", 
minViewMode: "months"});});
```

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
$mes=date("m",strtotime($_POST['datepicker']));
$year=date("Y",strtotime($_POST['datepicker']));
echo $_POST['datepicker'];}?>
```

lo que en resumen estoy intentando es que al elegir una fecha, esta se muestre en el datepicker, pero cuando eligo una, se queda en blanco.

Comment: Deberias agregar tu codigo

Comment: Hola @alanfcm, ya añadi el codigo :) tenia dudas porque segun lei se debe poner lo menor del codigo posible, gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.